# Python fails importing submodules from built wheel

Tags: python-3.x, pip, dependencies

I am trying to build a Python (3.7) module that has a structure similar to this:

```
module_dir/
├─ setup.py
├─ my_module/
│  ├─ utils/
│  │  ├─ common.py
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ dao/
│  │  ├─ base_dao.py
│  │  ├─ dwh/
│  │  │  ├─ dwh_dao.py
│  │  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
```

But I am having some issues:
when I import from this module in other projects, I am getting an ImportError.

In particular, my `dwh_dao.py` file contains the following import:

```
from dao.base_dao import BaseDAO
```

And it seems to make the import fail, but if I replace this import with a relative one, it works:

```
from ..dao.base_dao import BaseDAO
```

So far so good, but from `dwh_dao.py` I am also trying to reach `utils.common` and I cannot do that with a relative import AFAIK.

Therefore my questions are:

- Is there any way to go up more than one level in a module using relative imports?
- Why is my library failing to resolve absolute imports and I need to replace them with relative ones?

**EDIT1:**

Including my `setup.py` as well

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

setuptools.setup(
    name="my_module",
    version="1",
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description="ACMECorp Internal Shared Library",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    ],
    install_requires=requirements
)
```

**EDIT2:**

If I use absolute imports also in my library's `dwh_dao.py` file, like

```
from my_module.dao.base_dao import BaseDAO
```

Then it works, but why in a common project it would have been fine to use

```
from dao.base_dao import BaseDAO
```

and in a library project I also have to include module name in the import itself?

Comment: I recommend always using absolute imports, from my point of view there is not much point in trying to use relative imports. -- We would need more details about what happens when you say that absolute imports do not work. For example: what command are you executing? -- Note that you should not call something like `python mymodule/dao/dwh/dwh_dao.py`, but you should call somehting like `python -m mymodule.dao.dwh.dwh_dao` for example.

Comment: @sinoroc i am not creating an executable module but a python library, which I convert to a wheel file and install on other machines. When I import my library as a dependency (`from mymodule.dao.dwh_dao import MyClass`) it doesn't work and it complains about how I import base_dao in dwh_dao inside my library

Comment: I am not following. Are you having a circular dependency issue?

Comment: @sinoroc This module is saved as a wheel file, which I use in other projects. Whenever I run some code that imports my module, I get an ImportError  if I use absolute imports (in my module, not in the code using it). If in my module I use relative imports, then the project using my module as a dependency executes without raising an ImportError

Comment: I get that, but there is too little info in the question for me to figure out what causes this. My gut feeling is that it could be some form of a cyclic import issue, but it doesn't explain why switching to relative imports would fix it, so I am not following... -- What is the full error message? Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: please show your setup.py

Comment: For relative imports there always has to be a leading dot. You can use more leading dots to go higher up.

Answer (score 0):

> why in a common project it would have been fine to use
>
> `from dao.base_dao import BaseDAO` and in a library project I also have
> to include module name in the import itself?

Python have a packages hierarchy. When you package a project in a standard way (this is why I wanted to see your `setup.py`) the main package is `mymodule` and the pip installer makes sure it will be found in the python `sys.path`. This is why importing `mymodule` or `mymodule.dao` is working.

Now when you run your code directly from the command line or IDE things might be different. This is mostly dependent on your **working directory** or **PYTHONPATH**

If you want to simulate exactly what will happen after `pip install`, do the following:

- Open a python on the **project folder** (module_dir in your case)
- Make sure your PYTHON_PATH is empty (it should be).
- Try to import from the python.

You will see that `import dao` is not working.

However, if you will do it from the `my_module` folder (guess this is probably what you did) `import dao` will work. This is happening because the current folder is implicitly in the `sys.path`